# Error when using namespaces - class not declared

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm new to C++ and using namespaces and I can't see what I'm doing wrong here. When I compile the code below, I get the error:

```
error: 'Menu' has not been declared
```

Here is my header file Menu.hpp

```
#ifndef MENU_H //"Header guard"
#define MENU_H

namespace View
{
class Menu
    {
    void startMenu();
    };
}
#endif
```

and my Menu.cpp:

```
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;

namespace View
{
 void Menu::startMenu()
    {
    cout << "This is a menu";
    }
}
```

Comment: `#include "Menu.hpp"` in your `Menu.cpp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to include header `Menu.hpp` in your cpp file `Menu.cpp` like

```
#include "Menu.hpp"
```

Answer (score 4):

You missed including the header file which defines the class.

**Menu.cpp:**

```
#include "Menu.hpp"
```

Each **[translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)** is compiled separately by the compiler and if you do not include the header file in `Menu.cpp`, there is no way for the compiler to know what `Menu` is.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise each class had to include it's own header.